# JSON exctract key for fill Spinner

Tags: android, json, spinner

I would like to extract into two separate array the key **"desc"** and **"type"** in my JSON file.
I get the file from an ftp site and I don't know how many entry there are.
After I have the String Array, I would like to fill a Spinner by the "desc" value.
How can do that?

this is my JSON file

```
{
"Pagnerine":[{
        "Cialda":[{
                    "userId":1,
                    "desc":"Sottozero/Estate",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":2,
                    "desc":"Piccolo/Primavera",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":3,
                    "desc":"Medio",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":4,
                    "desc":"Grande",
                    "type":"ct"
                    }
                ],
        "Cartone":[{
                    "userId":1,
                    "desc":"16B",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":2,
                    "desc":"17",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":3,
                    "desc":"34",
                    "type":"ct"
                    },
                    {
                    "userId":4,
                    "desc":"20",
                    "type":"ct"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
"Cucchiaini":[],
"Vaschette":[],
"Zuccheri":[],
"versione":"100"
}
```

i have tried to implement this code for obtain how many entry (desc or type) there are, but fail because count only the first part **"Cialda"** and **"Cartone**"

```
Iterator<String> iter = jObj.keys();            
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        try {
                            JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray(key);
                            // looping through
                            entry += jArray.length();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest implementing an easier to maintain solution for this so you can get it into easy to use POJOs and adapt to potential changes later on. My preferred approach is to use [GSON}(https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), but there's also [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core).

Take a look at the [GSON User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for specifics, but basically here's the concept.

Let's say that my JSON is the following:

### JSON

```
{ "items" : 
  [
    {
      "type" : "food",
      "name" : "Tacos"
    },
    {
      "type" : "food",
      "name" : "Bacon"
    },
    {
      "type" : "food",
      "name" : "Beer"
    },
  ]
}
```

I would create the following objects:

### Items.java

```
public class Items {
  List<Item> items;
}
```

### Item.java

```
public class Item {
  String type;
  String name;
}
```

Then I would simply do the following to create my Items object once I got the JSON.

```
Items deliciousFoodStuffs = gson.fromJson(json, Items.class);
```

This would result in me having deserialized my JSON into POJOs which I can use to my hearts content.

Let's say that I don't want to map via the field names but instead map to Java fields named differently, I would do the following instead:

### Item.java

```
public class Item {
  @SerializedName("type")
  String typeValue;
  @SerializedName("name")
  String nameValue;
}
```

Using the same call as before

```
Items deliciousFoodStuffs = gson.fromJson(json, Items.class);
```

I will receive the same result with this, expect my variables are named differently.

Note: Beer, Bacon, and Tacos are all delicious and not necessarily organized in the order of deliciousness.

Comment: Just take what I did above and convert it over for your use. As you can see what it does when it is deserializing is take the field name (so "type" for example) and put the value that matches it in there.

I'll add a sample in-case you want to map a different JSON element name to a different Java field name. I don't want to do it for you since then you won't be able to debug it. Take a look and if you need specific help with what you are doing feel free to post what you've tried and I'll take a look.

Comment: ok, i have implemented the first version, (i have changed the JSON file structure), but is possible to know how many Items there are in the JSON file, because I have added one Item 

"type" : "Pagnerine Cialda",
"name" : "Pagnerine Cialda Grande"
"size" : "ct"

and I would like to fill one Spinner1 with TYPE data and after the user select one type fill the second Spinner2 with the Item that have the type equal at the Spinner1...I hope is clear...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please update your question with the new code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted doesn't match your objective in the question. But to answer the issue of why `entry` only counts the first two elements (and assuming jObj is a valid `JSONObject` containing the `Pagnerine` element) Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject childObject = new JSONObject(jObj.get(i).toString());
    entry += childObject.length();
}
```

`entry` should now contain the total number of elements there are in your JSON file. The change is to iterate through each of the parent elements (in this case `Cialda` and `Cartone`), and for each of these elements count the number of child elements.

**Edit**
As per your comment, this can be amended easily to get a count of the parents, and children:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
    parentCount += jObj.length();
    JSONObject childObject = new JSONObject(jObj.get(i).toString());
    childCount += childObject.length();
}
```

Comment: ok, but how can count how many parent and  childObject?
because the file is an archive of product and can change all day